# Cannot hide a view inside View controller with CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4

I am using a UIView item on my view controller that contains a picker view and a button, which needs to appear on the screen only when the show button is clicked.

I created a outlet for my UIView with name *pickerView

The default position of this view (on the right properties bar of Xcode) is (0,200,320,261) for (x,y, height and width) which basically makes it appear at the base of the ViewController.

What I did for this view to hide initially when the view controller loads is, in the ViewDidLoad method I put this code:

```
pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0,450,320,261);
```

For the action of show button,

```
pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0,200,320,261);
```

I have a hide button inside this UIView, in its action i have

```
pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0,450,320,261);
```

SO, from what I expect when I run the application, the UIView pickerView should initially hide because of code in viewDidLoad, and show button should bring it on the screen.
My problem is show and hide button works fine, but every time I load this ViewController the View appears on screen by default. Help me hide this UIView when I load the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

Simpley don't set the frame for picker view 
i am posting a sample code it makes picker view hide and appear when tapping the button 
i am using the property "hide"
hear is the sample code

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                         //as simple dont set frame.
                         // i am using xib from there i wired up picker view
  self.myPickerView.hidden = YES; //just hide it whenever you dont use it.

 }

- (IBAction)whenShowHideButtonTapped:(id)sender
 {
     //when button pressed just show it
     if(self.myPickerView.hidden)
      {
         self.myPickerView.hidden = NO;
      }
     else
      {
         self.myPickerView.hidden = YES;
      }

}
```

hope this helps .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call the hide code in 'viewWillAppear:' like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self hidePicker];
}
```